# How to use object comparision for custom objects in dart/flutter

Tags: list, dart, comparison, custom-object, object-comparison

I have a collection of dishes.

I want to retrieve all restaurant who have a specific list of dish in his menu.

My data model is this:

```
restaurant---->rest1
      |         |-->menu
      |                   | --> 1: true
      |                   | --> 2: true
      |                   | --> 3: true
      |--->rest2
      |         |-->menu
      |                   | --> 1: true
      |                   | --> 2: true
      |                   | --> 3: true
      |--->rest3
      |         |-->menu
      |                   | --> 1: true
```

my list of dishes is [1,2] for this reason I want to retrieve only `rest1` and `rest2`

my code is this:

```
Future loadRestaurantsByDishes({List idPiatti})async{


    idPiatti.forEach((element) async {
      dynamic result2 = await _restaurantServices.getRestaurantOfDish(id_piatto: element["dishId"].toString());
      rest.add( result2);
    });
    if(rest.length >0){
      List<RestaurantModel> mom = [];
      List<RestaurantModel> temp = [];
      rest.forEach((item) {
        if(mom.isEmpty){
          mom.addAll(item);
        }else{
          temp.addAll(item);
          mom.removeWhere((element) => !temp.contains(element));
          temp = [];
        }

      });
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }


Future<List<RestaurantModel>> getRestaurantOfDish({String id_piatto}) async =>
      _firestore.collection(collection).where("menu."+id_piatto, isEqualTo: true).get().then((result) {
        List<RestaurantModel> restaurants = [];
        for (DocumentSnapshot restaurant in result.docs) {
          restaurants.add(RestaurantModel.fromSnapshot(restaurant));
        }
        return restaurants;
      });
```

My idea is to retrieve all resturant who made a specific dish and after retrieve the common elements between those lists in order to retrieve the only restaur ant which have all of them.

The problem is that `mom` in the first statement is equal to item, but when I run `mom.removeWhere((element) => !temp.contains(element));` it returns an empty list.

Where I'm getting wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Hi there. Try making a reproducible demo using `https://dartpad.dev/` if possible. You question seems to be more about manipulating lists rather than `firebase`. So try creating basic sample list and try to perform the manipulation you are trying in the dartpad.

Comment: yes, the problem is in manipulation of strings in order to go forward to firebase limitation :), I used the pad and on basic list, my code seems to work, the problem is with list of custom object.

Comment: You define your custom objects in dart pad and create sample custom objects ? wouldn't that help making a demo ?

Comment: I tried also in this way `void main() {
  List l1 = [
    {
      "catId": '1'
    },
        {
      "catId": '2'
    },
      
  ];
  List l2 = [{
      "catId": '2'
    },
        {
      "catId": '3'
    },
      
  ];
  List l3 = [{
      "catId": '2'
    },
        {
      "catId": '4'
    },
      
  ];

  l1.removeWhere((item) => !l2.contains(item));
  l1.removeWhere((item) => !l3.contains(item));
  print(l1);
}` but I obrtain the empty one

Comment: Yes, it is giving `[]`. Now can you explain what output you expect ?

Comment: I want to retrieve common elements, in case of question `rest1` and `rest2`, while in case of dart pad `"catId":2`

Comment: This is because trying to compare Map<String, dynamic> will give that two cats with same id are not same because they don't have an `==` operator overload. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While comparing objects of custom classes you have created, you must override the `==` override and the `hashCode` function.

You can use the below explained method for you own custom classes in order to compare two of them using the `==` operator.

Try running this inside a [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/).

```
class Cat {
  String id;
  Cat(this.id);

  @override
  bool operator == (Object other){
    return other is Cat && id == other.id;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() => '{ id: $id }';

}

void main() {
  List l1 = [Cat('1'), Cat('2')];
  List l2 = [Cat('2'), Cat('3')];
  List l3 = [Cat('2'), Cat('4')];

  l1.removeWhere((item) => !l2.contains(item));
  l1.removeWhere((item) => !l3.contains(item));
  print(l1);
}
```

Comment: Cool! I forgot the override method for == and hashcode! Thank you so much!

Comment: @GTF Glad to have helped :) . This is a good question so I have upvoted it. People might have a similar problem. So I have edited the question to add correct tags and heading. If you feel the answer is adequate, please consider upvoting it as well so that it may reach more people.